# In the Lorentz force equations, can the magnetic field be assumed to be singular at one or more points?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, singularities

Consider the relativistic  Lorentz force equation (in a simplified form) given by
\begin{equation}\
\left(\frac{u'}{\sqrt{1-|u'|^2}}\right)'= E(t,u)+u'\times B(t,u).
\end{equation}
Here,  $E$ and $B$ denote respectively the electric and magnetic fields and are given by
\begin{equation}
E=-\nabla_u V-\frac{\partial W}{\partial t}, \qquad B=\mbox{curl}_u\, W,
\end{equation}
with $V:[0,T]\times (\mathbb R^3\setminus\{0\}) \to\mathbb R$, $W:[0,T]\times\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$  two $C^1$-functions.

The models I have seen so far deals with $V$ singular at one (or more) points ($0$ in this case, e.g.). My question is: there exists a relevant physical model in which also $W$ is singular at one or more point?

Comment: A classic example is the motion of a point charge in the field of a magnetic monopole of strength $g$, $\mathbf{B} = g \mathbf{r}/r^3$. The motion proceeds on a cone with the monopole at its vertex as e.g. discussed [here](http://kirkmcd.princeton.edu/examples/birkeland.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general solution for the magnetostatic case for the magnetic Vectorpotential (what you call $W$) is given by:

\begin{align}
{\displaystyle {\vec {A}}({\vec {r}})={\frac {\mu _{0}}{4\pi }}\int {\frac {{\vec {j}}({\vec {r}}')}{\left|{\vec {r}}-{\vec {r}}'\right|}}\mathrm {d} ^{3}r'\,}
\end{align}

If your $\vec{j}$ becomes singular, then $\vec{A}$ would be singular at that singularity as well. An often used model is the model of an infinitely thin wire that carries an electric current. This infinitely thin wire then carries a current distribution that is zero everywhere, except for points in the wire, where it takes on the values of a delta distribution. For that arrangement, the magnetic vector potential will become singular at all that points.

Comment: Quantumwhisp, thank you for the answer. I apologize for the dumb question but, as it is written, $A$ is already singular at $r=r^{\prime}$, isn't it? Also, could you please give a reference for that expression of $A$? Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_vector_potential is where the expression of A stems from. It is the solution of the maxwell-equations for a time independent charge distribution.

In this solution, there is an integral over all $r'$. So for abitrary $j$, there isn't necessarily a singularity.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, in case the potentials are due to a moving point particle, both scalar and vector potential are functions of distance with a component proportional to $1/r$.

Comment: Ján Lalinsky, thank you for your answer. Could you please explain me better why if $V$ and $W$ are due to a moving point particle, then they are both dependent  of distance with a component proportional to $1/r$? I apologize, I am not familiar with these things.

Comment: This is property of solutions of Maxwell's equations for a point particle, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential